# UI of this website is depressing

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface

I am sorry for being rude but overall design for this website is depressing. It does't look any creative or vibrant what a normal photographer seek.

A photographer is lover of color and if you see in there work you will see different shades, measures of light, brightness and so many known and unknown factors of beauty they keep introducing to worlds.

Every photographer have there own style but light and colour are their best friends during their entire journey. Even if it's white it is different white that you normally see.

But here in website specially dedicated for photographer is all dull and gray. I know designer's must have there reasons for so because in stack exchange network I don't believe we play lazy. We will love to hear those. And if possible we'll also love to see some new UI updates that doesn't look like a close depressing box.

My personal experience "each time I close this website window I sigh like just came out of a den". But I love all the knowledge that I get from this place, if it's pleasant to be here I am sure contributing will be lot more fun.

Comment: Replace `"dull and gray"` with "neutral" and you're fine. Create a different design an show it to us (at least for the dark grey header and page background). `"But I love all the knowledge that I get from this place, if it's pleasant to be here I am sure contributing will be lot more fun."` - focus on that.

Comment: Downvoting to disagree with the sentiment. **Given the fact** that the overall design follows from SE templates, I'd much rather plain gray than some of the other SE sites with graph paper or doodles or whatnot. I come here for the info, not the Squarespace-inspired design (or lack thereof).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you ever noticed that designers tend to wear simple clothing? That mannequins often [don't have faces](http://theshopcompany.com/white-egghead-female-in-hand-on-hip-pose-1602.html), or [even heads](http://theshopcompany.com/skin-color-headless-fiberglass-male.html)? That [*lorem ipsum*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwjlk-y0zZnKAhUGbD4KHR_bAE0QFggxMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLorem_ipsum&usg=AFQjCNG-uenyiXb2zEu5RR7y4e8q51JzQw&sig2=QjL9wb5Q0Pf0p4JA9cpYGw) doesn't mean anything? That products are often displayed and photographed alone? That when a musician wants to show off she plays solo?

This site is all about photography questions and answers and not at all about web design or stunning colors or splashy javascript effects.

**Focus on the part that matters.**

Answer (score 1):

Asthetic tastes vary widely, so beautiful to you may be the opposite to others.  A neutral gray is best for seeing pictures, so actually makes some technical sense.